# How PLT&GOT works in ARM(android)?

Tags: dynamic, assembly, arm, elf

I want to parse dynamic link function in ARM elf. As we know, when we call an extern function(fn1), it will jump to the relevant PLT position, and its PLT code will get an address from relevant GOT position. If fn1 is called first time, this address in GOT is the start offset of the PLT section, and the control is jump to there(and every PLT fn will jump to here at first time), to parse the real address of fn1, put it to GOT, and call it. And after that, when we call fn1 again, it will jump to PLT, and fn1's address is already in GOT, so we can call it directly.

That's my understanding, and I use gdb to verify it in x86 successfully. However, when I switch to ARM, the things seems strange. I found that **the PLT fn are not jump to the start offset of the PLT section to parse address, and GOT data is not the start offset of the PLT section nor the address of the extern fn after the program running.**(but it contains the start offset of the PLT section before running)

That's my debug setp in GDB:
**1. program's disassembly view**

```
.PLT
===========================================================================
.plt:000083D0                 AREA .plt, CODE
.plt:000083D0                 STR             LR, [SP,#var_4]!
.plt:000083D4                 LDR             LR, =(_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ - 0x83E0)
.plt:000083D8                 ADD             LR, PC, LR
.plt:000083DC                 LDR             PC, [LR,#8]!
.plt:000083DC ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.plt:000083E0 off_83E0        DCD _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ - 0x83E0 ;
.plt:000083E4 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.plt:000083E4 sub_83E4
.plt:000083E4                 ADRL            R12, 0x83EC
.plt:000083EC                 LDR             PC, [R12,#(off_90D4 - 0x83EC)]! ; sub_83D0
.plt:000083F0 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.plt:000083F0 sub_83F0
.plt:000083F0                 ADRL            R12, 0x83F8
.plt:000083F8                 LDR             PC, [R12,#(off_90D8 - 0x83F8)]! ; sub_83D0

.GOT
===========================================================================
.got:000090C8                 AREA .got, DATA
.got:000090C8 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ DCD 0             ; DATA XREF: sub_83D0+8
.got:000090CC                 DCD 0
.got:000090D0                 DCD 0
.got:000090D4 off_90D4        DCD sub_83D0            ; DATA XREF: sub_83E4+8
.got:000090D8 off_90D8        DCD sub_83D0            ; DATA XREF: sub_83F0+8
.got:000090D8 ; .got          ends

.TEXT
===========================================================================
.text:00008434                 ADD             R0, PC  ; "okkkkkkk..."
.text:00008436                 BLX             sub_83F0
.text:0000843A                 POP             {R4,PC}
```

**2. run arm-eabi-gdb**

```
// start gdb
(gdb) target remote :5039

// before running, GOT's data is ok
(gdb) x/2x 0x90d4  
0x90d4: 0x000083d0      0x000083d0

// PLT
(gdb) x/11i 0x83d0 
   0x83d0:      push    {lr}            ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
   0x83d4:      ldr     lr, [pc, #4]    ; 0x83e0
   0x83d8:      add     lr, pc, lr
   0x83dc:      ldr     pc, [lr, #8]!
   0x83e0:      andeq   r0, r0, r8, ror #25
   0x83e4:      add     r12, pc, #0
   0x83e8:      add     r12, r12, #0
   0x83ec:      ldr     pc, [r12, #3304]!       ; 0xce8
   0x83f0:      add     r12, pc, #0
   0x83f4:      add     r12, r12, #0
   0x83f8:      ldr     pc, [r12, #3296]!       ; 0xce0

// set a breakpoint at the fn(printf)'s plt
(gdb) b *0x83f0
Breakpoint 1 at 0x83f0

// running, before call printf at first time, the GOT's data is?
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Breakpoint 1, 0x000083f0 in ?? ()

// strange...
(gdb) x/2x 0x90d4
0x90d4: 0xafd14ff9      0xafd19b81

(gdb) ni
0x000083f4 in ?? ()

(gdb) ni
0x000083f8 in ?? ()

(gdb) i r
...
r12            0x83f8   33784
sp             0xbe9b2c38       0xbe9b2c38
lr             0x843b   33851
pc             0x83f8   0x83f8

// after 'ni', printf is called and output a string...
// will return to 0x843a
(gdb) ni
0x0000843a in ?? ()
```

That's all. **Even I put a breakpoint at 0x83d0 and run, it is not break totally!!!** Please help me...

Comment: What is your question?  Did you see [ELF for the ARM architechure](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044e/IHI0044E_aaelf.pdf), section 3.1.3 *PLT Sequences and usage models*?